# Extracting elements within curly brackets { } from a factor with several levels

Tags: r

I received a data file in which one value is within curly brackets comprising several different values, like this:

[1] {"Q0":"0","Q1":"1","Q2":"2","Q3":"3","Q4":"4","Q5":"6","Q6":"5","Q7":"4","Q8":"3"}

13 Levels:  ...

(Unfortunately I cannot provide an example as I do not know how to create this format.)

"Q0", "Q1" etc are different questions; and the values "0", "1", etc are the responses. I would like to create a data frame where "Q0", "Q1" are the column names and the values "0", "1", are numerical values.

But Im not sure how to extract the various parts. I have tried

```
 x[["Q0"]]
```

and

```
 getElement(x, "Q0")
```

Which gives: "Error in `[[.default`(x, "Q0") : subscript out of bounds"

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It s may be JSON

try

```
library(jsonlite)
json <- '{"Q0":"0","Q1":"1","Q2":"2","Q3":"3","Q4":"4","Q5":"6","Q6":"5","Q7":"4","Q8":"3"}'
fromJSON(json)
```

If data with `[`

`[{"Q0":"0","Q1":"1","Q2":"2","Q3":"3","Q4":"4","Q5":"6","Q6":"5","Q7":"4","Q8":"3"}]`'

your get `data.frame` else `list`

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!! I tried this with my object but got: Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file. Do you have any idea of why this might be?

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your help! It was JSON format; so I had to in R read the original file using fromJSON("JSONfile.csv")... and then use fromJSON again for that particular cell. Thanks!